# How to exclude a site wide margin-top on @media style?

Tags: css

I applied the code below to fix the alignment on my desktop site but it's also creating an unwanted margin on mobile. How can I exclude this effect on certain @media styles?

```
.site-container {
margin-top: 60px;
```

The site is: https://shiftins.com. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for example like this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
 .site-container {
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

or did I misunderstand something?

Comment: That's what I was thinking so I added it to @ media (min-width: 780px) and (max-width: 1020px) { but that did not work. I can't seem to find where in my stylesheet they defined the mobile widths. the 780px is the lowest one I found defined. Can you help me locate which width to put it under? @johannes

Comment: But that media query you quote is only valid for widths between 780 and 1200px. Everthing smaller will get the styles for the big screen again, if that's the only one. You need an additional media query with `@ media  sceen and (max-width: 779px)` into which you write that 'margin-top: 0px`

Comment: Thanks man there was a container for @media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {. I added it there works like a charm thanks for explaining!!

Answer (score 0):

I would first ask if you were using [Modernizr](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/modernizr) and see if you were using `bootstrap` for your site - to help with all the media queries.

Adding Modernizr should solve your issue, if not then comment and ill show you an alternative way.

Comment: I'm not even sure. I don't think so but again I couldn't tell you. I was hoping to make these changes directly to the CSS sheet.